# Smooth update only part of number in textview

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, uitextview, ticker

Do anyone have some idea about next problem:
In my app, I have textview with double value like 12242,25
I am updating that value every 100ms with step like 0,6

Currently I'm just changing the whole text with new value, but then I get that blinking because of changing all of numbers.

I would like to update only those decimals that are for real changing.

So on previous example, 12242, would stay (no text update), and i would update only last 2 decimals, from ,25 to ,85...and so on

Do anyone have some idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean everything keeps moving around, using a monospace font will keep your digits in the same place, so long as you format the string so the decimal point has a consistent number of digits before or after it (depending on whether the text is aligned with the left or right or it's centred)

If you mean it's actually blinking on and off, that shouldn't happen - it should just draw the current text, and the next frame after the text is changed it should just draw the new text. If that is a thing that's happening though, you might want to look into separate text views, one for each digit like a digital display. That way you're only changing the views for specific digits, but you'll need extra logic to work out which ones you're changing!

Comment: I ment that last cast.
It blinks because i'm updating that text(number) 10 times in 1 second (it just don't look nice).
So I tried to find some textview animation or logic for changing only parts of text that is for real changing.
Separate text view for every decimal should solve this problem.

Tnx a lot :)